# python 2.7: how to start python 3 instances within an application written in python 2.7?

Tags: python

I written an application using python 2.7. This application helps blind person to create a python project.
When a project is created It starts a python interpreter and an enitor in 2 separated tabs.
For each project a virtual environment is created.
Now, I want user can choose python version during project creation; so, if it selects python 3, a python 3 interpreter must start. I'm using phoenix as a graphic interface. Do I have to write 2 applications? onw for python 2 and an other for python 3, or I can use the same for all python versions? I think I can't start a python 3 interpreter within a python 2.7 program, but I'm not sure. I use nuitka to compile this program.

Comment: If Python 3.x is installed on the system, you can call it and interact with whatever is running in it from Python 2.x by using the `subprocess` module, more specifically: `your_process = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python3", "script_name.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` and then send and receive data to/from the process to your main process with `your_process.communicate()`. Same goes for running Python 2.x from 3.x...

Comment: Thanks, this is an idea!